# Three.js imported JSON model not receiving/casting shadows

Tags: javascript, json, three.js

I've been trying to work with blender exported models in Three.js, and I'm at the point where I can import the model, and see how light affects the object itself. I can see a directionalLight I used highlighting what's facing it, but I cannot cast shadows at all.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;
renderer.shadowMapType = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;
(...)
var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
directionalLight.position.set(30,10,-10);
directionalLight.castShadow = true;
directionalLight.shadowDarkness = 0.5;
directionalLight.shadowCameraVisible = true;
directionalLight.shadowBias = 0.1;
directionalLight.shadowMapWidth = 1024;
directionalLight.shadowMapHeight = 1024;
directionalLight.shadowCameraRight = 10;
directionalLight.shadowCameraLeft = -10;
directionalLight.shadowCameraTop = 10;
directionalLight.shadowCameraBottom = -10;
directionalLight.shadowCameraFar = 10;
directionalLight.shadowCameraNear = 10;
scene.add(directionalLight);


var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
loader.load( "island.json", function ( geometry ) {
    islandMesh = geometry;
    for(k in islandMesh.children-1){
        islandMesh.children[k].castShadow = true;
        islandMesh.children[k].receiveShadow = true;
    }
    islandMesh.castShadow = true;
    islandMesh.receiveShadow = true;
    scene.add( islandMesh );
    render();
} );
```

But even with what I believe is the whole setup that allows me to cast shadows done, I cannot get any shadow to be cast.
Here's a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Even though the light is coming from the right of the island, the mountains are not casting the shadows I expected them to.

I really appretiate any time you spend looking at this!

Massive thanks in advance, guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing will only work if you know the data in your json file have the structure of one parent with all the rest being a child of that parent. (still why are you doing `-1` in the for loop?)

What you should be doing (that works in all cases) is traverse the generated geometry tree:

```
islandMesh.traverse ( function (child) {
    if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
        child.castShadow = true;
        child.receiveShadow = true;
    }
}
```

**Edit**

For the directional light that you are using you probably have to adjust the

```
light.shadowCameraNear, light.shadowCameraFar, light.shadowCameraLeft,
light.shadowCameraRight, light.shadowCameraTop, light.shadowCameraBottom
```

CameraNear the default might be OK but you can bring it back to 1 and CameraFar depending on how far the camera is from the far end of the scene.

Comment: I tried replacing the for structure I had with the code you provided, but I'm getting the exact same result, even though this makes sense too. I appretiate the tip though!

Comment: I was using those definitions, but didn't mention them when posting, therefore I'll update the question post, with what I'm using. Even with all that defined, I get no shadows, sadly.

Comment: i cant tell from the code you posted but what are the dimensions of your scene like the bounding box. those numbers depend on that.

Comment: Well, they fit inside the shadow camera box, and the highest width on the object is about 10

Comment: is `light.shadowCameraNear === light.shadowCameraFar` as in your code above? near should be like 0.1 or 1 and make far 20.

Comment: And that was literally it! Thank you so much! It works wonderfuly well now.

With all the searching for a specific answer, I ended up using those properties without thinking much. I'm really glad you could help!